# Delete second row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete the second row of pandas dataframe but I was unable to do so.
Code used:

```py
df1.drop([1,],axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Note: The second row is empty that's why I want it gone.

Comment: Use ```df1.drop([1],axis=0, inplace=True)``` not ```[1,]```

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me

```
df1.drop(1, inplace=True)
```